# What is the correct way to take string from textarea and render it as html (email template preview)?

Tags: javascript, html

So in my app I'm trying to implement a component which allows the user to write html into a textarea. This html will be used for email templates, thus a preview of what the email would look like should be rendered below. I have a few ideas of how I can implement this, like simply taking the string and rendering it as innerHTML or I could also pass the html to the `srcdoc` property of an `<iframe>`. Both solutions seem very crude to me, so I'm assuming there's a much better/cleaner way of implementing this kind of requirement that I'm simply not aware of. Could anyone guide me on how to do this correctly?

I'm working with Angular if that's of any help.

Comment: What version of Angular?

Comment: Angular 5.0.0..

Comment: can you show your code?

Answer (score 2):

You can add text area change event `onchange` and apply your input html to div as 
html, refer below example.

html

```
<textarea id='txtArea'> </textarea>
  <div id='preview'></div>
```

Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#txtArea').change(function(){
        $('#preview').html(this.value);        
      });
    })
```

here is jsbin demo https://jsbin.com/bojalo/edit?html,console,output

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much what I did , albeit with Angular. The problem is that is that the user can also add styles for the email but when rendering them that way, they affect the entire app. I noticed that problem didn't occur when I rendered the html in an iframe, so I'm not sure if that would be a better solution. I'm just interested in knowing if there's some conventional way of implementing this. Like of there's another way which I don't know about.

Comment: if you are adding style in html it will affect to entire your html, yes should add in iframe